# Hedging with actual volatility: problem understanding the math behind the result

Tags: options, hedge

From [this paper](http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/110309_riaz_wilmott.pdf). page 3

We get that the total profit at expiration is the difference in value between the price of the option with actual volatility and the one with implied volatility.

I have tried solving the integral but I don't get the same result. I especially don't understand why the incremental value in both options cancel each other out.

$$e^{r\cdot t_0} \int_{t_0}^T d\left(e^{-r\cdot t}(V^i - V^a)\right) = V^a - V^i$$

I used the expression of the differential to solve the integral in the hope of getting the same result, but I get stuck with terms in $dV^i$ and $dV^a$

I get

$$ \left(e^{-r\cdot T} - e^{-r.\cdot t_0}\right)\left[ (dV^a - dV^i)/r  - (V^a - V^i) \right]$$

Comment: Could you please include the integral in the question and show us exactly where you're stuck in your equation solving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integration is over a full differential, meaning we can write:

$$ \int_{t_i}^T df(t) = f(T) - f(t_i)$$

Now, $V^i$ and $V^a$ represent the 'implied' and 'actual' value of the option, meaning they are time-dependent. This gives:

$$e^{r\cdot t_0} \int_{t_0}^T d\left(e^{-r\cdot t}(V^i - V^a)\right) =
e^{-r(T-t_0)} (V^i(T) - V^a(T)) - (V^i(t_i) - V^a(t_i))$$

Next, we use the fact that at the time of expiration the value of the options is completely determined by the stock price, and independent of the volatility. This means: $V^i(T) = V^a(T)$. What remains is:

$$e^{r\cdot t_0} \int_{t_0}^T d\left(e^{-r\cdot t}(V^i - V^a)\right) = V^a(t_i) - V^i(t_i)  = V^a - V^i$$

Comment: Thank you, i feel so stupid now. I think it's e^{-r(T-t_0)}

Comment: Yea, that was a typo.